# create a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems for this query :(
demo, the change table
http://www.dailychanges.com/

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `monitor_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `sitename` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `change` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `server` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `main_server` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5536 ;
```

please help :( for this query create

Comment: Please state the problem more clearly.

Comment: Please ask an actual question. There is nothing wrong with that query.

Comment: What's exacly wrong with that? What's the error? Working for me. Maybe you must select database first, or you have too little permissions.

Comment: What seems to be the problem, officer?

Comment: The question is vague, but I think that the answer listed is probably the issue (mysql version is older and doesn't allow varchar of greater length than 255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of mysql do you have? If you are running < MySQL 5.0.3 then VARCHAR has a maximum size of 255 (so varchar(500) doesn't work).